# SQL cast int to datetime

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql, select, casting

Why does this SQL statement:

```
Select cast(convert(1231231231,103) AS datetime)
```

cause an error:

> *#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near '103) AS datetime)' at line 1*

I need to convert `INT` to `DATETIME`, how to make it work?

Comment: Looks like you are using SQL Server syntax on MySQL. What datetime is `1231231231` supposed to represent anyway? Is it UNIX time?

Comment: 1231231231 is just an example, to be more close to reality it can be 1350134926. Yes, unix time

Comment: In T-sql you'd use Cast or convert normally, and Convert would be Convert(SomeType,SomeValue[,SomeStyle]), so you'd only bother with cast if you were casting the converted type to some other type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your integer is unix time you can use `FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp)`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime?

Comment: thank you! it works! Now the question is: How to make it engine independent (SQL Server, MySQL, T-sql ...)?

Comment: I don't think you will find an engine independent solution for this. MySQL and T-SQL are very different here as far as I know.